# Find files younger than a certain date containg a certain key word

Tags: 18.10, grep, find

How can I find/list all python scripts that are younger than a certain date and containing a certain word? I would also like to print the modification date in front of each file name if possible.

So far I tried this but it is also showing java files:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" -newermt "2019-01-01" | grep -Ri "Distribution"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the grep on each file using `-exec` and print the name and other information only if it succeeds:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" -newermt "2019-01-01" -exec grep -qi "Distribution" {} \; -printf '%Tx %p\n'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you :)